# For which values of $a$ does the following LP problem have an optimal solution

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, polygons

Max    Z= $\alpha \cdot x_1$ + $(1-\alpha)\cdot x_2$

(1) $2x_1$ + $x_2$ <= $4$

(2) $-2x_1$ + $x_2$ >= $0$

(3) $x_2$ >= 1

$x_1$ $>=$ 0

Given the following optimal solution polygon:

[image: The graph]

for which $\alpha$ values, (1,2) is an optimal solution?

a. $2/3 <\alpha<2$

b. $\alpha>2$

c. $\alpha<2/3$

I thought that the right answer is c because as long as I take smaller $\alpha$ I get higher value, but it seems to be the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

The $4$ vertices are $(0,1)$, $(0.5, 1)$, $(1,2)$, $(0,4)$.

The corresponding objective values are $1-\alpha$, $0.5\alpha + (1-\alpha)=1-0.5\alpha$, $\alpha +2(1-\alpha)=2-\alpha$, $4(1-\alpha)=4-4\alpha$.

Let's study the question when does $2-\alpha$ becomes larger than the rest,

- $2-\alpha \ge 1-\alpha$ is trivially true.
- $2-\alpha \ge 1-0.5\alpha$ is equivalent to $1 \ge 0.5\alpha$, hence we have $2 \ge \alpha$.
- For $2-\alpha \ge 4 - 4\alpha$, I would like to leave it as an exercise for you.

Comment: Ok,
2-a >= 4-4a,
-2 >= -3a,
3a >= 2,
a >= 2/3,
But how I can tell that a < 2 ?

Comment: I have shown that condition that $\alpha \le 2$ in my current working.  Hence we require $\frac23 \le \alpha \le 2$, which is a superset of option $a$.